# How to add a variable based on order of observation in a dataframe - R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to add a variable value to a dataframe based on the order of the observation in the data frame.

```
… Subject Latency(s)
1   A     25
2   A     24
3   A     25
4   B     22
5   B     24
6   B     23
```

I want to add a third column called `Trial` and I want the values to be either T1, T2, or T3 based on the order of the observation and by Subject. So for example, Subject A would get T1 in row 1, T2 in row 2, and T3 in row 3. Then the same for subject B, and so on.

Right now my approach is to use `group_by` in `dplyr` to group by Subject. But I'm not sure then how to specify the new variable using `mutate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mutate` w/ `row_number` & `group_by(Subject)`

```r
library(dplyr)

txt <- "ID Subject Latency(s)
1   A     25
2   A     24
3   A     25
4   B     22
5   B     24
6   B     23"

dat <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)

dat <- dat %>% 
  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  mutate(Trial = paste0("T", row_number()))
dat  

#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   Subject [2]
#>      ID Subject Latency.s. Trial
#>   <int> <fct>        <int> <chr>
#> 1     1 A               25 T1   
#> 2     2 A               24 T2   
#> 3     3 A               25 T3   
#> 4     4 B               22 T1   
#> 5     5 B               24 T2   
#> 6     6 B               23 T3
```

Created on 2018-03-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work for any number of subjects. To illustrate, copy and paste this code into your console.

```
library(dplyr)

d <- data.frame(subject = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","D","D"),
                latency = c(25,24,25,22,24,23,34,54,34))

# get counts of unique subjects
n <- d %>% dplyr::count(subject)

# create a list of sequences
my_list <- lapply(n$n, seq) 

# paste a "T" to each of these sequences
t_list <- lapply(my_list, function(x){paste0("T", x)})

# bind the collapsed list back onto your df
d$trial <- do.call(c, t_list)
```